# EclipseLink and Spring OXM Inheritance issues

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, eclipselink

I am stuck with the inheritance problem while trying to unmarshal to object. Here is my class

**A**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public abstract class A{
}
```

**B**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="B")
public class B extends A{
   String bField;
   @XmlAttribute(name="b")
   public String getBField(){
     return bField;
   }
   public void setBField(String value){
     this.bField = value;
   }
}
```

**C**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="C")
public class C extends A{
  String cField;
  @XmlAttribute(name="c")
  public String getCField(){
     return cField;
  }
  public void setCField(String value){
     this.cField = value;
  } 
}
```

**Container**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="container")
public class Container{
   ArrayList<B> listB;
   ArrayList<C> listC;
   public ArrayList<B> getListB(){
       return listB;
   }
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="list-B")
   @XmlElement(name="b")
   public ArrayList<B> getListB(){
       return listB;
   }
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="list-C")
   @XmlElement(name="c")
   public ArrayList<C> getListC(){
       return listC;
   }
   public ArrayList<C> getListC(){
       return listC;
   }
}
```

Then the input XML file

```
<container>
  <list-B>
    <b b="BFied"/>
  </list-B>
  <list-C>
    <c c="CField"/>
  </list-C>
</container>
```

I used EclipseLink JAXB integrated with Spring OXM. When i unmarshal xml file to an instance of Container, every thing is duplicated. In list B i have 2 B instances which duplicated ( the same thing with list C).

Please let me know where did i do wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  I am using the EclipseLink 2.4.0 which can be obtained from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Below is my complete code based on your question:

**A**

```
package forum11642669;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
public abstract class A{
}
```

**B**

```
package forum11642669;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
public class B extends A {

    String bField;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "b")
    public String getBField() {
        return bField;
    }

    public void setBField(String value) {
        this.bField = value;
    }

}
```

**C**

```
package forum11642669;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "C")
public class C extends A {

    String cField;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "c")
    public String getCField() {
        return cField;
    }

    public void setCField(String value) {
        this.cField = value;
    }

}
```

**Container**

The version of the `Container` class you had in your question wouldn't compile, so I've modified it below:

```
package forum11642669;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
public class Container {

    ArrayList<B> listB;
    ArrayList<C> listC;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list-B")
    @XmlElement(name = "b")
    public ArrayList<B> getListB() {
        return listB;
    }

    public void setListB(ArrayList<B> listB) {
        this.listB = listB;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "list-C")
    @XmlElement(name = "c")
    public ArrayList<C> getListC() {
        return listC;
    }

    public void setListC(ArrayList<C> listC) {
        this.listC = listC;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11642669;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11642669/input.xml");
        Container container = (Container) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(container, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
   <list-B>
      <b b="BFied"/>
   </list-B>
   <list-C>
      <c c="CField"/>
   </list-C>
</container>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,it's absolutely great to see this detailed answer. Maybe, i am the bad programmer or something magical appear. Yesterday, i keep the same source then run the program again , everything working perfectly :-? . EclipseLink has save me a lot of time from marshalling from XML , many thank for eclipselink project

Comment: Dear Blaise, now i figured out how the problem occured. My project is a maven project, inside eclise it run ok but when i use "mvn test", the problem occured. Don't really understand why.